# What is replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig," ") doing?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have come across come code written by another developer and I can not working out what it is doing:

```
title.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig," ")
```

Comment: As @RobW pointed out, you do NOT want to rely on this regex to block script injection.

Comment: Nice example why I *always* write down at least *what* a reg exp is supposed to do in a comment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It replaces all tags (substrings on the form `<...>`) with a space, `" "`.

Here's a regexp breakdown:

- `<`       - a left tag
- `[^>]` - anything but a right tag...
- `+`       - ...one or more times
- `>`       - a right tag.

The `(` and `)` just surrounds the groups in the expression, which are not used anyway.

The `/ig` suffix says that the regex is case **i**nsensitive (pointless in this case, since the rexeg doesn't mention any letters) and **g**lobal stating that all occurrences should be replaced.

Comment: Note that the parentheses are superfluous in this regex.

Comment: Also note that it is a very rough, incomplete RegExp to strip tags: `<tag value=">Evil?">` results in `Evil?">`, instead of `""`. And, the `i` flag is optional, since the pattern itself does not contain any case-sensitive characters.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's replacing HTML start or end tags.  If you ever need to parse Regex expressions or test them, here's a great site. http://myregextester.com/index.php

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?i-msx:                 group, but do not capture (case-insensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    <                        '<'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>]+                    any character except: '>' (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your outer parens are confusing, as they do not exist in the regex.

Comment: @Phrogz - They do exist but do not have to be added to the raw pattern. Regex is quite confusing sometimes, so you're not alone.